# How to get SimpleRpcClient.Call() to be a blocking call to achieve synchronous communication with RabbitMQ?

Tags: .net, rabbitmq, synchronous

In the .NET version (2.4.1) of RabbitMQ the *RabbitMQ.Client.MessagePatterns.SimpleRpcClient* has a Call() method with these signatures:

```
    public virtual object[] Call(params object[] args);
    public virtual byte[] Call(byte[] body);
    public virtual byte[] Call(IBasicProperties requestProperties, byte[] body, out IBasicProperties replyProperties);
```

**The problem:**

With various attempts, the method still continues to **not block** where I expect it to, so it's unable ever handle the response.

**The Question:**

Am I *missing something* obvious in the setup of the *SimpleRpcClient*, or earlier with the *IModel*, *IConnection*, or even *PublicationAddress*?

**More Info:**

I've also tried various paramater configurations of the QueueDeclare() method too with no luck.

```
string QueueDeclare(string queue, bool durable, bool exclusive, bool autoDelete, IDictionary arguments);
```

Some more reference code of my setup of these:

```
IConnection conn = new ConnectionFactory{Address = "127.0.0.1"}.CreateConnection());
using (IModel ch = conn.CreateModel())
{
     var client = new SimpleRpcClient(ch, queueName);
     var queueName = ch.QueueDeclare("t.qid", true, true, true, null);

     ch.QueueBind(queueName, "exch", "", null);

     //HERE: does not block?
     var replyMessageBytes = client.Call(prop, msgToSend, out replyProp);
}
```

**Looking elsewhere:**

Or is it likely there's an issue in my "server side" code? With and without the use of BasicAck() it appears the client has already continued execution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**--SHORT ANSWER--**

Bit of the "**You're doing it wrong**"...

> Check on *IBasicProperties*, and you should be using *SimpleRpcServer* with *HandleSimpleCall()*

If you stumble upon this question, you've either taken the wrong approach as I have, and possibly if made a similar mistake of manipulating *IBasicProperties* incorectly thereby hurting the ability of *SimpleRpcServer* to function correctly.

**--LONG ANSWER--**

**Working Sample for .NET:**
  Find my working example up on BitBucket here:

> https://bitbucket.org/NickJosevski/synchronous-rabbitmq-sample-.net

Or here's a quick sample...

**Client side:**

```
IConnection conn = new ConnectionFactory{Address = "127.0.0.1"}.CreateConnection();
using (IModel ch = conn.CreateModel())
{
    ch.ExchangeDeclare(Helper.ExchangeName, "direct");

    var queueName = ch.EnsureQueue();

    var client = new SimpleRpcClient(ch, queueName);

    var msgToSend = new Message(/*data*/).Serialize();

    IBasicProperties replyProp;

    var reply = client.Call(new BasicProperties(), msgToSend, out replyProp);
}
```

**Server side:**

```
IConnection conn = new ConnectionFactory{Address = "127.0.0.1"}.CreateConnection();
using (IModel ch = conn.CreateModel())
{
    ch.ExchangeDeclare(Helper.ExchangeName, "direct");
    var queuename = ch.EnsureQueue();

    var subscription = new Subscription(ch, queuename);

    new MySimpleRpcServerSubclass(subscription).MainLoop();
}

internal class MySimpleRpcServerSubclass : SimpleRpcServer
{
    public MySimpleRpcServerSubclass(Subscription subscription) 
        : base(subscription) { }

    public override byte[] HandleSimpleCall(
        bool isRedelivered, IBasicProperties requestProperties, 
        byte[] body, out IBasicProperties replyProperties)
    {
        replyProperties = requestProperties;
        replyProperties.MessageId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        var m = Message.Deserialize(body);
        var r = 
            new Response
            {
                Message = String.Format("Got {0} with {1}", m.Name, m.Body)
            };

        return r.Serialize();
    }
}
```

**Shared:**

```
//helper:
public static string EnsureQueue(this IModel ch)
{
    var queueName = ch.QueueDeclare(QueueId, false, false, false, null);

    ch.QueueBind(queueName, ExchangeName, "", null);

    return queueName;
}

//NOTE: 
not all extension methods are explained here, such as *.Serialize()* 
as they're not relevant and just make for a cleaner example.
```

Comment: Have you considered running `.MainLoop()` on a separate thread using something like `System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(...MainLoop);`?  The reason I ask is because I have code that needs to listen to a few separate queues and I think that means I have to have a SimpleRPCServer for each queue that runs its own MainLoop on a separate thread.  I can't find a good example of this online.